# All added links open as target, how to prevent it?

Tags: navigation, wysiwyg

In my Drupal based website, all links that I added from CKeditor open as (target="_blank"

```
Link example: (<a href="node/add/name">Name</a>)
After adding, example from html source: (<a target="_blank" rel="nofollow" href="node/add/name">Name</a>)
```

As you see, the 'target="_blank" rel="nofollow"' added automatically.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: How can I make it default? When I add a link from block area as filtered html, I see same problem.

Answer (score 0):

In CKeditor  when adding a link it will ask

click -> **hyperlink** button ->in **Target** set it as  will resolve your issue.

or if you have installed **external**  module means disable it.

Comment: Hello,

How can I set default settings for this issue?